# Are there more than three Superfun Adventures of Jax?

Tags: comics, the-superfun-adventures-of-jax

I've finished the first three issues of [*The Superfun Adventures of Jax*](http://www.comixology.com/The-Superfun-Adventures-of-Jax/comics-series/7859), which wrap up the story of who Jax is, and the battle between the Great Fish in the Sky and the Motheater.  It seems like this initial story is setting the scene for more 'superfun adventures', but I can't find mention of whether this is just a three-issue story, or there's more.

Is it known if there are going to be more issues?  Is the story of Jax, Ash, the Woodsman, and the Fish continued in another comic?  (I still get confused trying to track stories from one comic series to another).  Are there more issues, but only in print, so hard to find mention of online?

Answer (score 8):

I decided to email the writer and illustrator of the Superfun Adventures of Jax.

> At present, this was just a one shot but I appreciate that you liked the work and I am currently working on something.  Thanks for the support and I appreciate you writing.
>
> Sincerely,
>
> Britt Snyder

With the completion of the graphic novel it sounds like that will be all for Jax.